# referencing css files with django

Tags: css, django

I'm new to the Django framework and am having a little bit of trouble following the documentation for including CSS files.

I have set up a media root in settings.py
MEDIA_ROOT = '/home/daniel/django/site1/media/'

MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

And within that I have my css folder and file

/home/daniel/django/site1/media/css/style.css

Now in my html files how do I then reference the CSS file?

As I am in local development, I have done what the Django Docs have send and kept MEDIA_URL as '/static/'.

To then reference the files, do I have done this, but to no avail.

Could someone please point me in the right direction.

Thanks,

Dan

Answer (score 1):

you should be able to include your css like so:

```
    <link href="/static/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Also, if you're running the django dev server, you have to enable static file serving.
Try adding the following to your urls.py:

```
from django.conf import settings

urlpatterns = patterns('',    
   (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
                               {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
```

Please note that for production use you should disable static file serving within django, and configure your webserver to take over the serving of static content.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work with that, and I tried before with

Comment: <link href="{{STATIC_URL}}/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> too.

Comment: are you using the django dev server? If so have you enabled static file serving?

Comment: Yes, I am. But these are automatically enabled unless you choose to use another server for local development.

Comment: "also, if you're running the django dev server, you have to enable static file serving. Try adding the following to your urls.py:

(r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
    {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),"

Comment: I receive an NameError: name 'settings' is not defined

Comment: ok, sorry about that -you need to import the settings into your urls.py, like so: `from django.conf import settings`

Answer (score 0):

Append to `urls.py`:

```
from django.db import settings
# Media (development)
# Serves media content. WARNING!! Only for development uses.
# On production use lighthttpd for media content.
# Set DEBUG to False in production.
if settings.DEBUG:
    # Delete the first trailing slash, if any.
    if settings.MEDIA_URL.startswith('/'):
        media_url = settings.MEDIA_URL[1:]
    else:
        media_url = settings.MEDIA_URL

    # Add the last trailing slash, if have not.
    if not media_url.endswith('/'):
        media_url = media_url + '/'

    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^' + media_url + '(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve',
            {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}
        ),
    )
```

And then in your template:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ MEDIA_URL }}css/style.css" />
```